# How to disable outside touching to hide DialogPreference

Tags: android, dialog-preference

i'm developing a custom DialogPreference.

When user clicks outside the dialog, it is cancelled and i need to avoid this.

I know that Dialog has method `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel)` that is what i need but the DialogPreference not.

in `onBindDialogView` i try:

```
getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

but `getDialog()` returns `null`.

How can i do? Can someone help me?

This is my class:

```
public class UpdatePreference extends DialogPreference implements View.OnClickListener{


    public UpdatePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setPersistent(false);
        setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.update_dialog_layout);
        setPositiveButtonText("");
        setNegativeButtonText("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
        super.onBindDialogView(view);   
        //init my components
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
        super.onDialogClosed(positiveResult);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access `AlerDialog.Builder` before dialog will be shown. There you can specify `builder.setCancelable(false)`. Probably in such way you can achieve desire behavior.

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) {
    super.onPrepareDialogBuilder(builder);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
}
```

Comment: Just excelent answer.